# Having trouble installing and removing MySQL in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, server, software-installation, mysql, webserver

I have trouble in installing or removing the partly installed mysql-server-5.6 in ubuntu15.04. 
The error I am getting was

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.6
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server-5.6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
22 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,501 kB of archives.
After this operation, 50.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.6.24-0ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path                 /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/locale: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/man: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/gnome/help: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/omf: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/doc/kde/HTML: 0 KiB

Total disk space freed by localepurge: 0 KiB

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Better can remove and hopefully a clean re-install would be fine i think.

Comment: I tried this process still i have the problem, ie i am ubable to uninstall or reinstall mysql server

Comment: I tried my level best to find out the cause for the issue. I removed the data from the apt status file and updated the apt, where I noticed the system is experiencing the problem with libgcc1  libc6. I am trying to solve the problem Will keep post the status based on my findings.

Answer (score 79):

Try doing a purge, then re-install.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Update 04.09.2018:
If you have issues uninstalling/installing because MySQL process is live, you can try this first, then above:
`sudo kill $(pgrep mysql)`

Comment: I tried this process still i have the problem, ie i am ubable to uninstall or reinstall mysql server

Comment: The original instructions removed the metapackage, which was a no-op. The new edited instructions work with 16.04.

Comment: Worked for me on elementary OS.

Comment: This worked for me **only** after I checked `ps -aef | grep mysql` and sent a kill signal to all varieties of running mysqld.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about killing mysql! I had uninstalled it but somehow it was still running (???) and then my new install got stuck on 94% around `Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf ...update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode`

But killing mysql did it!

Answer (score 19):

A very simple solution which I (the linux noob) had to dig up... is to create the file.

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
```

and fill it with the default content from the mysql-common 5.7.11-0ubuntu6 package.

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

found [here at apt-browse.org](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/xenial/main/all/mysql-common/5.7.11-0ubuntu6/file/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback)

Comment: This is a better answer than the accpeted one because it fixes the actual problem without having to use the brute force approach.

Comment: In my case `touch /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback` got me past the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Purge/Reinstall also did not work for me. I found the following "solution":

I could not find `mysql.cnf.fallback` listed in the "provided files" for `mysql-server-5.6` / `mysql-client-5.6` nor any additional info about the file.

I copied `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback` (guessing that this would have been a relatively less important "fallback" config file);

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is a symlink, so `ls /etc/mysql` now shows:

```
 my.cnf.fallback -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
 my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
```

The installation of the package then completed without error (since presumably the "doesn't exist" issue was "solved").

I have not come across any adverse effects (yet).

Comment: This sounds great but can you explain the reason for the problem, It would be beneficial for others.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem while trying to purge mysql-server (5.7.14).

In case that the my.cnf* files are missing, you can re-install the package **mysql-common**, and afterwards, you can purge both (**mysql-server & mysql-common**)

These my.cnf* files belong to **mysql-common** package (see bellow):

```
$ dpkg -L mysql-common | grep cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

1. **Re-install mysql-common**

> apt-get install --reinstall mysql-common

2. **Purge mysql-common**

> apt-get purge mysql-common

Answer (score 6):

Confirmed. Order matters.

```
apt remove mysql-* mariadb-* --purge
apt install mysql-common
apt install mariadb-common
apt install mariadb-server
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved it for me and should be the anwser.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by charneykaye in the comments, this approach can fail if there's some `mysql` processes in the background. I used:

```
emil-mint-desktop ~ # ps -aef | grep mysql
root      6682     1  0 16:45 ?        00:00:00 sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
root      6683  6682  0 16:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql     7046  6683  0 16:45 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306 --log-syslog=1 --log-syslog-facility=daemon --log-syslog-tag=
root     21046  9812  0 17:32 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Killed the first 3 processes (the last one is the `grep` call itself!) using:

```
kill -9 6682 8883 7046
```

Then remove everything `mysql` related:

```
apt remove --purge mysql-\*
apt autoremove
apt autoclean
```

and then install:

```
apt install mysql-server
```

Then it worked.

Versions:

- Mint 18.1 (based on Ubuntu). You will need to substitute `apt` for `apt-get` for some other versions.

Comment: Followed these steps and worked on Ubuntu when trying to install mysql-server from the standard apt repo (moving from Oracle's APT repo).

The purge step prompted to remove databases and lib files which I denied. It still cleaned up the environment to get mysql-server to install properly. +1

Answer (score 1):

I checked my `/etc/mysql/` folder and found it to be completely empty other than an empty sub-folder `conf.d`.

```
cd /etc/
# you need to delete the empty mysql folder otherwise the ln below creates the link inside the existing mysql folder
sudo rm -r mysql
sudo ln -s ./mysql.bak/ mysql
```

then (courtesy of this link [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109698/dpkg-dependency-problems-prevent-configuration-of-initramfs-tools))

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and now all appears okay.

The link above also mentions `--force-depends` but I did not need this.  It also mentions `apt-get -f install` but again I did not need this.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution for that:

First step: `apt-get install mysql-common --reinstall`

Second step: `apt-get install mysql-server --reinstall`

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the answers above I was able to fix this problem with:

```
sudo rm /etc/rc5.d/S03mysql
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
sudo apt-get -f install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```