# Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 Mysql 5.6 install not working

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I read a lot about the issues here with mysql server and client 5.6 on ubuntu 14.04 and tried all the things but I cannot get it to work.

Following steps I already took

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

error from installation

```
Setting up mysql-common (5.6.25-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't
exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help here?
thanks a lot

Comment: Your problem is very similar to the one mentioned in the thread - http://askubuntu.com/questions/643251/having-trouble-in-installing-and-removing-mysql-in-ubuntu You might want to try the solution listed in it.

Comment: yep I already tried this, but this does not work for me either.
I found another discussion where it was mentioned that a VM needs more RAM, I also increased it to 2048 but without success
nvm I'm now bootstrapped a container with debian then :/

Comment: Any solution in above case ??? I am also stuck with the same

Comment: I found that the mysql was present but completely empty and it was not just the `my.cnf.fallabck` file that was missing