# Install MySql 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, 16.04

It seems that Ubuntu 16.04 is coming with MySQL 5.7, however I need to install 5.6.

When I try to install it explicitly `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6` I get the following error:

```
Package mysql-server-5.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mysql-community-server:i386 mysql-common:i386 mysql-community-server mysql-common percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6:i386 percona-server-server-5.6:i386 mysql-testsuite-5.7:i386
  mariadb-server-10.0:i386 percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6 percona-server-server-5.6 mysql-testsuite-5.7 mariadb-server-10.0 mysql-server-core-5.7:i386 mysql-server-5.7:i386 mysql-server-core-5.7
  mysql-server-5.7
```

Is there any way to install 5.6?

Comment: That mysql 5.7.12 is a RAM hog.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks that I managed to do it.

1. In **Software & Updates**/**Other Software** added 14.04 repository:

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
   ```
2. Installed mysql client and server:

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6
   sudo apt install mysql-client-5.6
   ```

**Update:** Before installing 5.6, make sure that no other mysql packages are present:

`dpkg -l | grep mysql` - returns list of mysql packages.

Use `apt-get purge <package name>` to purge them.

**Source:**  [16.04 upgrade broke mysql-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server/760886#760886)

Comment: Good solution, but why do you need 5.6 instead of 5.7?

Comment: 5.7 is not backward compatible. Some SQLs of application I'm working on fail...

Comment: What error are you getting? I suspect that it is due to the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY flag which is "on" by  default in MySQL 5.7. Set it to off and you may be fine.

Comment: Currently I don't remember the details, I tried it almost two months ago. If I remember correctly, it was about some dates processing. Maybe parsing of dates.

Comment: 5.7 actually enforces table schema

Comment: @Tarlog Did you actually get this to work and run as a service ? I get all kinds of issues with this.

Comment: Yes, running since this post on Apr 25th

Comment: You rock! This solution finally worked for me after so much wandering.

Comment: @Tarlog I have the same problem on a serveur installed with 5.7. I tried to do like you, but apt-get desesperately insist to tell that 5.6 is obsolete. Sure you only execute points  1 and 2 ?? I'm also on ubuntu 16.04.4.

Comment: This doesn't work, apt insists that 5.6 is obsolete.

Comment: Sorry about that, it worked 3 years ago :) I moved to DynamoDB since then.

Answer (score 75):

I used the following approach:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6 mysql-client-5.6
```

If an error occurs during the execution of the last command take a look at the comment section of this answer.

Comment: You may need to `sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag` or it will abort with `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: the mysql service doesn't start properly. using  'systemctl status mysql.service' I get 'Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon'. Is this because the Trusty repo uses upstart and 5.7 uses systemd ?

Comment: @jowansebastian - Did you ever find out why this was happening? I'm having a similar error.

Comment: @BarrieReader no sorry, I created a centos VM for what I was doing and got it working in there fine.

Comment: +1. Would you know whether there's a way to install a specific version of MySQL 5.6 like 5.6.35?

Comment: If mysql-server-5.6 is failing to start you may nee to unmask it with: `systemctl unmask mysql.service`

Comment: The raw directions above worked for me, but in order to start the service and then schedule it to automatically load during boot, I had to issue `sudo systemctl start mysql && sudo systemctl enable mysql`

Comment: Also, there is a bug with this version of MySQL that leads to the my.cnf not being read due to it being a symlink. For details see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39454735/2831606

Comment: If you get error `add-apt-repository: command not found`, then you would `software-properties-common` package as well which will be enough for Ubuntu 16.04 
`apt-get update && apt-get install software-properties-common`

Answer (score 9):

I was facing same issue and I have performed simple steps below:

```
 sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
 $ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

Solution worked for me Cheers!!

Comment: In addition to this solutions: You must remove these folders first:
`/etc/mysql/`
`/var/lib/mysql`
`/var/log/mysql`
`/var/lib/mysql-filters`
`/var/lib/mysql-keyring`
And this file: `/var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag`

Comment: To quote ondrej: *"don't use, broken"*. Check out here https://launchpad.net/~ondrej

Answer (score 3):

```
dpkg --force-depends -P `dpkg -l |awk '/mysql/{print $2}'`

rm -r /etc/mysql/

apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I tried a lot of options. And I had a lot of problems with `libdbd-mysql-perl`; the system said that was not going to install that library.

So I thought to install it with the Aptitude that install a package and correct all the dependencies.

If you don't have aptitude you can get it like this:`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

First all you need to uninstall your existing mysql.
Next you need to install the package that you want.

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server-5.6
```

The aptitude give you a lot of option, what to do. The first options is to keep the actual package. 
So press (N)o until you find the option that say to downgrade the next packages:

```
libmysqlclient20 [5.7.14-1ubuntu16.04 (<NULL>, now) -> 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16
mysql-common [5.7.14-1ubuntu16.04 (<NULL>, now) -> 5.6.30-1+deb.sury.org
```

then press (Y)es and the aptitude is going to install the mysql-server-5.6. Here's the option that you should accept:

[image]

If after that the system cannot connect to mysql server you need to restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL developers provide Xenial packages of MySQL 5.6 in [their own repositories](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/), **and this should thus be preferred over installing the official Ubuntu Trusty packages**, since it is in general better to install packages which were created for your version of Ubuntu.

If you already have MySQL Server packages, you should first uninstall them; just uninstall everything that is shown by `dpkg -l | grep mysql-server`.

Just download and install the `mysql-apt-config` DEB package in the previous link. During the installation, it will ask which version you want, so you can choose 5.6. After the package is done installing, `sudo apt update && sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6` will install MySQL Server 5.6.

Comment: This doesn't work, there is no 5.6 version option, only 5.7

Comment: Indeed it seems that since this answer was written, MySQL 5.6 support was removed from the `mysql-apt-config` package, which is weird because it is still listed as supported on the linked page...