# Can't install MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, 16.10, held-packages

I was following this instruction https://askubuntu.com/a/765458/490870

```
duke@ostrov:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6
[sudo] password for duke: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: initscripts but it is not installable
                    Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but it is not installable or
                             file-rc (>= 0.8.16) but it is not installable
                    Recommends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
duke@ostrov:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1):

I am also using Ubuntu 16.10, and the default version of mysql-server in my computer is 5.7 and it's working fine.

Try following commands:

```
    sudo apt-get install -f
    sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.6
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

If you still get broken packages error, try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to fix it. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) might be also helpful for you to fix broken packages.

*(PS: This may not work, I put my answer cause I don't have enough reputations to comment, Hope it can help you!)*

Comment: There is no default MySQL for Ubuntu. And I already installed `5.6.35` with `dpkg`. But the `apt` issue is still opened anyways.

Comment: this does not answer the question, which is how to install mysql 5.6 .