# Failing to start mysql.service for MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, mysql

After following the [instructions in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/765458/119948) on how to install MySQL 5.6 over an existing 5.7 installation on Ubuntu 16.04 I had multiple problems starting the service.

First this happened:

```
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked
```

Which was solved by running `systemctl unmask mysql.service`. However then I repeatedly had this message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Inspecting `systemctl status mysql.service` showed:

```
Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
```

Answer (score 11):

After Downgrading MySQL version I am also facing this try following command

```
systemctl unmask mysql.service
service mysql start
```

Answer (score 2):

The fix for this contained multiple steps including different debug logs and then following clues in those logs. I'm documenting them to help others - your problems might be different but this process should help to discover what's wrong:

Firstly `journalctl -xe` contains a lot more information. In my case it contained:

```
kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1528794958.103:169): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback"
```

This could be fixed with `vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and adding lines for:

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf/ r,
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf/* r,
/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback r,
```

An interesting point is that it needs a separate line for a directory and wildcard files within it - this can be common for some unix applications but not all so might trip you up.

Once all the apparmor changes were done the system still wouldn't start, and this time the `journalctl -xe` command yielded nothing useful.

I was then able to run `sudo -u mysql mysqld` to try starting the daemon manually. This showed a failure with InnoDB starting up, but not why.

On a whim I deleted the files `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*` and `ib_binlog` and tried again; this time the server started. I was then able to terminate this and run `service start mysql` which worked.

Separately I deleted `/var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag` - I am unsure if this helped or would have caused subsequent problems if I had not done so.

Hopefully this example helps somebody; please feel free to add other answers along a similar line if you encountered different problems with this process.

Comment: Indeed apparmor can be sometimes hasle :)

Comment: i completely purged apparmor, and this still happens!

Comment: @thang as in you still get apparmor denied errors? It's likely apparmor still contains some references to SQL as part of a default config maybe? Try completely disabling it (temporarily) and seeing the the errors persist - if they do there's something odd going on with your system!

Comment: i got it going.  i had to uninstall mysql and reinstall it, then manually remove everything apparmor related in /etc and /usr.  i don't know how much of that is necessary, but that works.

Answer (score 0):

First stop mysql, if it is running

```
BACKUP=/var/tmp/broken-mysql
sudo mkdir -p $BACKUP               # create backup dir
sudo mv -vi /var/lib/mysql* $BACKUP # Remove any old database setup
sudo mysql_install_db -u mysql      # Install new database
sudo systemctl unmask mysql.service # Enables the service for systemd
sudo service mysql start            # Start the service
```

Comment: This is really dangerous!! I edited, so you don't delete all your data in the first place. But still, this doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 18.10