# Cannot install MySQL in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, server, permissions, mysql

I am new to MySQL and I am having trouble installing it for a few days now. I was running MySQL and these are the things that I did.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and entered my root password, then
I created a new user using

```
mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ananyapam'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql>\q
```

Entered using the new user

```
mysql -u ananyapam -p
```

(Succesful!)
Then tried deleting the new user ananyapam using

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'ananyapam';
```

Now when I listed my users and there was no user ananyapam.
However, now when I try to create the user ananyapam again using

```
mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ananyapam'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

it returns an error message. Not understanding much after a while of searching, I thought of removing and then reinstalling it using the commands below:

```
 sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
 sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I then tried to reinstall MySQL using this

```
 sudo apt install mysql-server
 sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

it returns error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This link might be useful for someone:[Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint' - installing mysql?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835628/access-denied-for-user-debian-sys-maint-installing-mysql)

Edit:
@Melebius suggested [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238531/250300) but after

```
mysql> SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             |                                           | auth_socket           | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *477880DFF7642ABC170F60991A43E7FFB8B000E4 | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

it returns an error message

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _“now when I try to create the user ananyapam again using `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`…”_ This is not how a [user is created](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html). _“I thought of removing and then reinstalling it using the commands below”_ What was the output of those commands?

Comment: It was successfully removed, the error message comes while installing it again

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238531/250300)?