# Impossible to fix broken MySQL5.7 after automated update

Tags: 16.04, mysql, stable-release-updates

MySQL5.7 on Ubuntu16.04 has just broken after a MySQL update came through
I have tried all the options in this [16.04 upgrade broke mysql-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server), and then went further, purged everything that related to any version of MySQL - and I still end up with the following.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 to upgrade, 6 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/18.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 275798 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 275955 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu11) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there ANYTHING that anyone can please recommend - I am really getting fed up with the increasing failures on ubuntu when upgrades are made.

This is as a direct result of an utomated update that happened on 25 October 2016.

Comment: Did you try running apt-clean ..... Maybe the downloaded copy has got corrupted

Comment: Thanks - I did that too, it downloaded a lot of stuff when I tried to reinstall, but failed again with the same error

Comment: Seems they have fixed the issue at some point. After uninstalling and reinstalling twice per day ... suddenly today it actually worked.  Then I had the wonderful experience of following very bad and incomplete instructions how to change the root password - I am frankly starting to think that ubuntu is becoming worse than Windows ...

Comment: What happens if you manually install all the dependencies and then install MySQL?