# Error installing mysql-server: "Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' plus apparmor error "Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL on my Xubuntu system. I've been having problems installing it for an entire day now. I tried installing it and removing it multiple times, but of course the problem didn't magically solve itself.

With mysql-server uninstalled, I typed the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

And I'm getting the next output from it:

```
Fri Dec 30, 13:05, ~ $ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 199729 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 199886 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                       Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu13) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I correctly install MySQL?

Comment: Did you try removing it with `sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server`, then do `sudo apt -f install && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt install mysql-server` ?

Comment: Purging MySQL like that gave the same error, so I tried sudo apt remove --purge mysql*, which worked. I hadn't tried sudo apt -f install, so I did this time, then reinstalled using sudo apt-get install mysql-server. Same problem.

Comment: use `sudo apt install mysql-server` not `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` . Please purge it again before trying again.

Comment: I just tried. It's still doing the same thing.

Comment: what version of xubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50945/discussion-between-george-and-yop).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [16.04 upgrade broke mysql-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server)