# Can't reinstall mysql : mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7 however: Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

I've been trying to uninstall and reinstall MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04, I've seen plenty of methods but I can't figure out why I'm getting an error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mi 2017-04-26 12:15:04 EEST; 5ms ago
  Process: 13693 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

apr 26 12:15:04 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
apr 26 12:15:04 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
apr 26 12:15:04 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried these steps:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Everything goes well, until I use `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

If I run `systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mi 2017-04-26 13:30:19 EEST; 11min ago
  Process: 17650 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

apr 26 13:30:18 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
apr 26 13:30:18 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
apr 26 13:30:18 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
apr 26 13:30:19 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
apr 26 13:30:19 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
apr 26 13:30:19 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
apr 26 13:30:19 alex-X750JB systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql-server`.

Comment: mysql-server     install
mysql-server-5.7    install
mysql-server-core-5.7    install

Comment: run `sudo apt autoremove  mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7  -y`

Comment: By the way, you can just reinstall it using `--reinstall` command, no need to uninstall  ;)

Comment: i've run it, still the same error after trying to install again

Comment: You mean `--reinstall`? After running the `autoremove` command which I mentioned before, run this: `dpkg -L mysql-server-5.7` post the output at [Ubuntu paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com) then send the link here.

Comment: This is the output @Ravexina http://paste.ubuntu.com/24459566/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57746/discussion-between-ravexina-and-nita-alexandru).

Comment: @Ravexina i've managed to do it and i started it, if i stop the server could it brake again?

Comment: I don't think so ... glad that it's solved :)

Comment: i'm glad aswell, after that it was masked and i had to unmask it

Comment: Do this: sudo systemctl disable mysql.service && sudo systemctl enable mysql.service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server) and i managed to reinstall mysql-server and it ran.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Since your link refers to another Ask Ubuntu question, it may also be prudent to flag this question as a possible duplicate instead.