# Uninstalling Mariadb and installing MySQL

Tags: 16.04, mysql, mariadb

I had MariaDB installed on Ubuntu 16.04. Then tried to replace it with MySQL. After un-installing MariaDB now MySQL won't be install and I receive this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also run `rm /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql -r` to delete configuration files, but no chance.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server

Comment: @GraysonKent Uninstalling `dbconfig-mysql` was the only thing which solved the problem.