# update to ubuntu17.04 with mysql-server failed with initscripts dependency

Tags: server, apt, upgrade, mysql, 17.04

After install some update to ubuntu17.04 and remove mysql-server with `autoremove`, I meet this error:

```
mysql-server-5.7 : 依赖(dependent): initscripts 但无法安装它(but can't install it)
sudo apt install initscripts
# 没有可用的软件包 initscripts，但是它被其它的软件包引用了
# 这可能意味着这个缺失的软件包可能已被废弃，
# 或者只能在其他发布源中找到
# no valid package initscripts,but it referred by other package
# this means it may be abandoned, or can be found in other repo
# replaced by following
# sysvinit-utils util-linux:i386 sysvinit-utils:i386 util-linux
```

with `sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7`.
I have tried [16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server), but still break with above problem!

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by update with [MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=472393)

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.7-1_all.deb
sudo apt update
```

and select 5.7 with `OK`

1. **backup `configure file` and `databases`**
2. `sudo rm /etc/alternatives/my.cnf /etc/mysql  -fr`
3. `sudo rm  /var/lib/mysql/* -fr`
4. `sudo apt remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-community-client  --purge`
5. `sudo mkdir -p  /etc/mysql/conf.d/`

   > else `error with mysql-server (--configure)` ==> /etc/mysql/conf.d/ not found in /etc/init.d/mysql restart
6. `sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client --fix-broken --fix-missing`
7. **restore configure_files and databases with the backup files**
8. `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Hope this will save your time! Good Luck!

***BTW***: `Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked` ==> `systemctl unmask mysql.service`
***MARK***: `dpkg-query -l mysql*` to queuy state of package.