# mysql installation error

Tags: mysql

When I try to install mysql-server i get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: my ubuntu version is 17.04

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's already installed but failed during the process.
Try removing all previous installations by typing

```
apt purge mysql-server
```

and if necessary

```
apt purge mysql-server-5.7
```

and then retry the installation by typing

```
apt install mysql-server
```

(which is a meta package btw, it will install the latest MySQL Server version)

Comment: Whenever I install any package after the installation the same error pops up

Comment: Well this must be a problem whith dpkg then. Is your system up-to-date?

    apt update && apt upgrade

What's the output of that?

Comment: my system is uptodate but whenever i run those commands, after all the process i get the same error

Comment: apparently someone had the same issue and a solution has been given https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server

Comment: but all the step in it is done. And i am still stuck with issue

Comment: well, in this case, have you considered using mariadb instead? This works the same appart from the fact that it will stay opensource