# MySQL 5.7 upgrade won't complete

Tags: apt, upgrade, mysql

APT isn't able to upgrade mySQL for me. I believe the 1045 error is due to login details. I'm able to run mysql_upgrade -uroot -p and finish it manually but how do I tell apt that it's done, please stop trying?

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf because link group my.cnf is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /etc/mysql/my.cnf with a link
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Unknown error 1045 while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: concerning `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1`: read my answer from this related problem  https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server/793545#793545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to recreate the debian-sys-maint user with the password from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you disabled the mysql service at startup, the upgrade script fails to complete the update process. Therefore, you can enable the mysql service at startup and upgrade it like following,

```
sudo systemctl enable mysql.service

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade -y
```

If you want to disable mysql service at startup, you can disable it like following,

```
sudo systemctl disable mysql.service
```

Comment: Hi @bkayranci it would be helpful if you explained what those commands do for anyone else following along.