# MySQL 5.7 server can't be reinstalled

Tags: apt, 18.04, mysql

After problems with MySQL server that couldn't finish an update properly (5.7.24). I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/762432/100771). So basically, I can come back in a "stable" state when after running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

All is working, MySQL is removed and no error are returned. (I could do the apt purge without error). There are no more `/etc/mysql` nor `/var/lib/mysql` directories. And the last dpkg doesn't find anything to do and returns nothing.

I reboot to be sure. But now, when I am doing :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I am getting this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Saying that is still not configured and there are dependency problems. So the install can't finish with success.

When running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

It returns:

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.7 est cassé ou partiellement installé
```

Can't be done because **mysql-server-5.7** is broken or partially installed. So, is there a way to really return to a fresh state? I don't have to keep existing MySQL databases or configurations. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you need to fool `update-alternatives` by doing `sudo update-alternatives --remove my.cnf`. At least, that may get rid of the first error.

Comment: To get a fresh state, you can remove all `mysql*`  packages. First get installed packages that start with `mysql` with `sudo apt list --installed | grep -i -E '^mysql`. If you don't see anything that you need to keep, remove them all with `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`.  That command will also remove configs and dependencies installed related to mysql* packages. If you see something that you need to keep, remove them one by one or with a more restricted regex. After that you can try again.

Comment: @bistoco Yes I have done this. The purge works well. I don't have any MySQL package in my system anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I will answer to my question, thanks for the help, so what I have done after many try/error:

First, ensure you can run these commands without any error: (don't hesitate to reboot to avoid locks in apt)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Delete: (do backup before if you want but do no leave the files in these directories, even with .bak or .old extensions)

- /etc/mysql
- /var/lib/mysql

If you have an error mentioning alternatives, run: (replace my.cnf) by the file indicated in the error message)

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove my.cnf
```

Then reinstall:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Check now, if at least the mysql service is running:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

If still not OK, try to force reinstall:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server --reinstall
```

And reconfigure:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove All

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean
rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Greetings!

Comment: This does not seems to answer the question which is to reinstall mysql server.

Comment: sudo apt install mysql-server