# Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried everything relevant that I can find inside this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server)

But nothing for me so far as fixed this issue. I have never had mysql successfully installed. As I had tried to install `phpmyadmin` before installing mysql which meant I aborted the `phpadmin` install and then oddly, during my `mysql-server` install the `phpmyadmin` confirgue screen poped up.

So its a mess :D

```
hutber@hutber:~$ ps -ef | grep mysql
999       3952  3925  0 12:51 ?        00:00:36 mysqld
hutber   27307 27070  0 23:56 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

```bsh
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get purge mysql*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysqltcl' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.1' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-utilities' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-sandbox' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysqltuner' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench-data' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.1' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-source-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Package 'mysql-client-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' instead of 'mysql-common-5.6'
Package 'mysql-server-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-sandbox' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-utilities' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-workbench' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-workbench-data' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysqltcl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysqltuner' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-source-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libevent-core-2.1-6
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libevent-core-2.1-6
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 251 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 342618 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libevent-core-2.1-6:amd64 (2.1.8-stable-4build1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.1-6 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libevent-core-2.1-6 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 to upgrade, 7 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/20.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 342614 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.8+1.0.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.1-6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.1-6:amd64 (2.1.8-stable-4build1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.4) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 342775 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.1-6:amd64 (2.1.8-stable-4build1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

*Edit 2*

````bsh
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7 phpmyadmin --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore php php-php-gettext php-phpseclib php7.2
Suggested packages:
  php-libsodium php-mcrypt php-gmp
Recommended packages:
  javascript-common php-gd php-bz2 php-zip php-tcpdf
The following NEW packages will be installed
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore php php-php-gettext php-phpseclib php7.2 phpmyadmin
0 to upgrade, 9 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,813 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Internal Error, No file name for mysql-server-5.7:amd64```
````

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` at this point?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep mysql` please.

Comment: Updated question, and yes. The dpkg just returns nothing. Straight back to a fresh terminal entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a # instruct dpkg to "fix" itself
sudo apt-get -f install # correct dependencies and continue to configure your packages
sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7 phpmyadmin --reinstall
```

Regarding the `E: Internal Error, No file name for mysql-server-5.7:amd64` error message please search the answers to [E: Internal Error, No file name for mysql-server-5.7:amd64](https://askubuntu.com/q/760724/).

Comment: Update question again :) I will search for what this error means.

Answer (score 0):

Have been struggling with this, and did this:

```
sudo apt purge mysql*  
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt-get -f install  
sudo apt autoremove  
sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7 phpmyadmin
```

A dialog box turned up, and I chose "ignore", and it seems to work. Mysql up running and web service up running, at least.