# Error when trying to load mysql to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dpkg, mysql, moodle

I'm new to Ubuntu so apologies if the answer to this is obvious. I tried searching for similar problems on the forum but couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to load mysql as part of a LAMP stack to run Moodle. However, I'm encountering an error trying to load mysql. This is all the info from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-client mysql-server php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1).
libapache2-mod-php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  gnome-video-effects
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common
  mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 php7.0
0 to upgrade, 9 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 10.0 kB/18.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client all 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [10.0 kB]
Fetched 10.0 kB in 0s (82.3 kB/s)       
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64.
(Reading database ... 209205 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I subsequently ran dist-upgrade and got this message:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-video-effects libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client-5.7:
 mysql-client-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.5); however:
  Package mysql-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client-5.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
 mysql-client-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please, run `sudo apt-get update`, then, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, after that, do `sudo apt-get autoremove`, and finally, `sudo apt-get autoclean`. Then reboot your computer, and try the installation again.

Comment: Hi - thanks for getting back to me. I followed the instructions but the same thing happened again. There was an error message is got when running the dist-upgrade - which I will try to post below as it's too long for a comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/643251/having-trouble-in-installing-and-removing-mysql-in-ubuntu

Comment: I think you are right - I checked out the first solution on this thread and it worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble in installing and removing mysql in ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643251/having-trouble-in-installing-and-removing-mysql-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing mysql workbench for running db queries.
Installing `lampp` and starting it by

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

will connect mysql.