# After upgrade to 16.04 - alternative link error setting up mysql-common

Tags: upgrade, mysql, system-settings

My OS was updated to 16.04

During the upgrade there was a problem with mysql. This is the error message:

```
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /etc/mysql/my.cnf is already managed by my.cnf.bak
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried the solutions that were proposed in the following questions and none of them worked for me. The solutions that were tried:

1. [Error Installing mySql on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766038/error-installing-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04)
2. [Having trouble installing and removing MySQL in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643251/having-trouble-installing-and-removing-mysql-in-ubuntu)
3. [16.04 upgrade broke mysql-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server)
4. [Having trouble installing and removing MySQL in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643251/having-trouble-installing-and-removing-mysql-in-ubuntu)

Is there any suggestion for another solution? Thanks

The output of ls -l /etc/mysql is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 22 17:29 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  839 Sep 19 13:52 my.cnf.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  839 Jan 21  2017 my.cnf.fallback
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  839 Sep 19 13:51 mysql.cnf
```

Comment: Which "all solutions"  were proposed that you tried? This information will help us avoid wasting time suggesting solutions you've already tried. Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then [edit] your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Please [edit] the output of `ls -l /etc/mysql` into this post as well. I've edited your post to avoid having it closed as too broad. Please ask a different question regarding your system settings issue and include the error message that popped up on that. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Are you certain that you followed all the answers to the questions you listed in there entirety? https://askubuntu.com/a/762432/225694 looks promising. Pay close attention to step 3 and read the comments as well. I would especially draw your attention to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server#comment1145221_762432) and [that one](https://askubuntu.com/users/139735/starbeamrainbowlabs)

Comment: I followed https://askubuntu.com/a/762432/225694 and after step 4 I got the following error message:    update-alternatives: error: alternative link /etc/mysql/my.cnf is already managed by my.cnf.bak
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
 Thanks.

Comment: Please review my previous comment entirely.  your output indicate that you clearly have a my.cnf.bak file in /etc/mysql as well as a my.cnf.fallback file. and ignored [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server#comment1145221_762432) which I drew your attention to entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed the file /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf.bak and it works!

Comment: Thanks @SharonH I spent two hours around these posts installing and uninstalling mysql, till I saw your comment.